# What is a "massive phase" in the string theory or CFT?

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory

When reading through some articles, one encountered a vocabulary termed as a "massive phase" in the string theory or the CFT, in the case where a theory followed an RG flow between UV and IR.

What was the "massive phase"? Does it mean actual (effective or unnormalized)mass? or does it just mean "high energy"?(If it meant high energy, then how to distinguish or define "high" energy? was there a coupling constant?)

Comment: In the context of CFT, massive phase means there is a mass gap between the ground state(s) and excited states in the spectrum.

Comment: @MengCheng, If it flows to a nontrivial CFT in the IR how can there be a mass gap? (I mean this as a question not a comment)

Comment: If it flows to a nontrivial CFT in the IR, then it is not a massive phase.